# Какой вариант записи условий оптимальнее?

Tags: c#

```
if( test1 && test2 && test3){
    Done();
}
```

---

```
if(!test1) return;
if(!test2) return;
if(!test3) return;
Done();
```

---

```
if(test1){
    if(test2){
        if(test3){
            Done();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Первый (надеюсь test1 test2 test3 - это не настоящие имена переменных ;-) )

Comment: Зависит от ситуации

Comment: Оптимален в чём? Скорости? Удобстве чтения? Количестве кода?

Comment: Замечу так же, что 1 и 3 вариант - абсолютно идентичны.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не должны думать о нанооптимизациях вроде перестановки строк. Думайте о смысле кода. Смысл во всех трёх случаях одинаков, поэтому и разницы по сути нет.

То, что должно вас волновать — это то, как вам легче прочесть и понять код. А вот какой из трёх вариантов читабельнее, решать вам. Мне лично третий вариант не нравится избыточной вложенностью, но в вашем коде выбирать вам.

---

В текущей версии ассемблерный код, генерируемый для этих трёх функций, [немного неодинаков](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxNMAfAAgBgARYCMA3ALABQWAzAQEx4DCFA3hXuwTcAPbcA2eeLEJJBcWLVFCYVMuQ542HagQAseALKEAFAEol7VvIUcAlgDM826YTwAyO2In3H0qvuMm8Rr14Ai3AB2cHpyvngAvgaR0dEqWOoatHrRPr4WVgCENroEAOxh6Zba2eIwtLlYBdEKGSVuldWeJgHBodFRzXE0CZpUKc1pXnU5NRxD4XgjZRVjXhOTZsUNc5MLiy1BIbqFGxydewe+R+wnis29rdt4ALwAfASEAJzaAEQAJluvOxQRQA=). Но это лишь временное несовершенство JIT-компилятора; например, компилятор C++ Clang со включенными максимальными оптимизациями компилирует все три куска в [одинаковый объектный код](https://godbolt.org/g/qhAQWP).

Answer (score 2):

С точки зрения скорости исполнения, то это будет одно и тоже, в любом случае компилятор всё это оптимизирует, и выходной после компиляции код, будет не такой как вы написали в коде C#.

Но с точки зрения красоты кода, самый лучший вариант 1ый как наиболее понятный и прозрачный.

Красота кода это очень важный параметр, так как в реальном проекте рефакторинг и разбор кода может быть до 80% от общего времени программирования, поэтому ясный и понятный код очень важен.

```
if( test1 && test2 && test3){
    Done();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

С точки зрения скорости работы, все варианты, как мне кажется, примерно одинаковые.

С точки зрения количества сгенерированного кода компилятором, варианты 1 и 3 примерно одинаковые, в варианте 2 будет чуть больше кода.

С точки зрения читаемости кода, я бы предпочел вариант 1